# Is there a function of $y$ that satisfies these constraints?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, special-functions, constraints

Given $y>0$ I want to find least $\alpha\geq1$ and regions of $m$ and $x$ that satisfies
$$y^{x}\leq m^\alpha$$
$$m\leq\frac{(1-3x)\log y}{4\log(1-3x)-4\log 2+4\log\log y}$$

$$1+\frac1{x}\leq m$$

How can this be done?

Comment: Where did this come from?

Comment: @martycohen it came from a difficult constraint satisfaction problem. I do not know what I have is satisfiable.

Comment: This must be a very complex problem, for sure. Could you describe a bit more the context ?

Comment: I think if $\alpha\geq2$ there is always solutions.